# best way to download from a list of cloud storage buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

what's the best way to download from a list of cloud storage buckets besides doing:

```
gsutil cp gs://path1 .
gsutil cp gs://path2 .
gsutil cp gs://path3 .
...
gsutil cp gs://path1000 .
```

Ideally also capturing the error messages

I tried

```
for i in [gs://path1 gs://path2 ..]
  do gsutil cp $i .
done
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you please say more about what didn't work? Was it that the paths were collapsed (dropping all the files into one download directory), or that you didn't get enough error details, or that it took too long, or ... ?

Comment: it simply shows "bad pattern: [gs://path1 " and nothing is downloaded with the loop. if i add quotation around gs//:path1 etc the error msg is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's linux for loop typo. Do the same without the []

```
for i in gs://path1 gs://path2 ..
  do gsutil cp $i .
done
```

Comment: if i need to read this long list from a text file like this:
while read -r line; do
gsutil cp  $line .
done < gsPaths.txt
it's getting InvalidUrlError: Unrecognized scheme "'gs". any advice on how to get around that? @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: If you have 1 path per line, or each path separated by a space, I recommend you to use cat like that `for i in $(cat myFile); do ...; done`